# Android Kotlin DownloadManager could not work for unknown reasons

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement a download function with DownloadManager in order to download .mp3 from my self-host server. My destination is the app folder (not external folder), but I could not figure out why the following codes do not work....

```kotlin
private fun downloadAudio(audioFilename: String, audioURL: String){
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_1MG.mp3"))

        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)

        println("${applicationContext.filesDir}/${audioFilename}.mp3")
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(File("${applicationContext.filesDir}/${audioFilename}.mp3")))

        val manager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        manager.enqueue(request)
    }
```

The error returned was

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.storyteller2, PID: 6332
    java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /data/data/com.example.storyteller2/files/test.mp3
```

I dont understand why the path is unsupported? why it is related to security excpetion anyway?

Thank you very much for your help!!